# what is the "16 bit short address"?

Tags: networking, embedded

I'm using CC2538EM and CCS v6.

i had founded RF example project, and i had studied few days.

and then i got a question about 16 bit short address.

when i used  basicRfSendPacket(RX_ADDR, (unsigned char*)&tTxPacket, PACKET_SIZE) this function, I thought RX_ADDR was Rx_FIFO address. but it wasn't

RX_ADDR was defined 0xBEEF.

and i founded this value is short address.

what is short address ?!

Is that address located in RAM ?
Is it specific address of register ?

that value was allocated 
SHORT_ADDR0 , SHORT_ADDR1 and described "The short address used during destination address filtering".

What is the address filtering either..... ?

help me..

Regrads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "short address" is a configuration parameter of the RF transceiver contained in the CC5238 system-on-chip (SoC).  Compare it with other configuration parameters such as "extended address" and "PAN ID".

Here is an excerpt from the CC2520 Software Examples User’s Guide:

> uint8_t basicRfSendPacket(uint16 destAddr, uint8* pPayload, uint8
>   length)
>
> Send packet to the given destination short address. Returns TRUE if
>   packet was sent successfully, and FAILED otherwise. If ackRequest is
>   TRUE the return value of this function will only be TRUE if an
>   acknowledgment is received from the destination.

The first parameter of `basicRfSendPacket()` is the short address (think like a network address) of the RF tansceiver that you're sending the packet to.  It is not a memory address for RAM or a register.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!
i had been very confused that was a memory for RAM or a register.